# Como editar un archivo externo de PDF desde ABAP SAP

Tags: archivo, pdf, sap, abap

yo sé que esta plataforma es para preguntas de programación, pero me encantaría saber si alguien tiene algún conocimiento de donde puedo consultar o cómo puedo editar un archivo externo de tipo PDF en ABAP SAP, ¿ya que desconozco de cómo hacerlo y quisiera saber si hay forma de que se pueda o no?

Si hay forma de cómo hacerlo o donde consultarme se los agradecería mucho, se aceptan cualquier sugerencias o ideas que hay, pero lo que más me interesa es que si se puede editar ya el archivo PDF importado en ABAP SAP?